# Windows Deployment System- the system cannot find the file specified

Tags: windows-7, sysprep

I am using sysprep and Windows Capture (part of WDS) to create a windows 7 image. Sysprep and the wizard run fine as I enter the appropriate data. However, at the start of the image creation I get an error message saying 'Creating image... the system cannot find the file specified' after which the process is aborted. Any ideas of what might be the issue? Thanks

Comment: Are you using the Image Capture Wizard when the image saving process begins? Are you saving to network or to a local/USB disk?

Comment: The image capture wizard starts from LAN and boots an image just containing the wizard, which starts the imaging process The system allows you to optionally save to network but local save is compulsory. Changing to only local still causes the same problem.

Comment: Do you have permission to save to the LAN directory?

Comment: yes, and it shouldnt matter, as I have said, it still fails when saving the image locally only.

Comment: Ok. For the record, you didn't say anything about permissions so I was asking to rule it out. Anyway, moving on, do you have enough space + a load extra on the WDS server to cater for the temp file and the final wim location? Also enough temp space on the source machine?

Comment: sorry no offence intended. yes & yes. Both the machine and the WDS have 150GB+ free